# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I have updated my material-ui to 0.15 yesterday from 0.14.4 and and react to 15.0.2 for material ui, I have followed the instructions [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes) to compute a valid muiTheme and pass it down to components, since muiTheme is no longer avaiable by default in 0.15 release of material-ui

When I try to run my app it gives the following error

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `Main`.

**Render Method for Main.jsx :**

```
return(
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
            <div style={{width:'100%',height:'100%'}}>
                {this.state.logged_in && this.state.toolbar ? 
                    <TopToolbar location={this.props.location} />
                : null }
                {this.state.login_check_done ? this.props.children : <Loading/>}
                {this.state.logged_in && this.state.btnAddTrip ? 
                    <FloatingActionButton onClick={this.addTrip} backgroundColor={baseStyles.colors.turquoise.color} style={{position:'fixed',bottom:15,right:15}}>
                        <ContentAdd/>
                    </FloatingActionButton>
                : null }
                <MySnack/>
                {this.state.screen_cover ? <div id="screen_cover" className={this.state.cover_dark?'semi_dark':''} /> : null}
                {this.state.spinner ? <div id="spinner"/> : null}
            </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
        )
```

Comment: Whats the stack-trace of the error? It'd help to pinpoint which component inside your `render` method is causing this exception.

Comment: did you import the MuiThemeProvider from `material-ui/styles/` or `material-ui/lib/styles/` ?

Comment: @AakashSigdel @HazardouS , I imported the MuiThemeProvider correctly, I have resolved the issue, the issue was with FloatActionButton, I used `require()` instead `import`